# How do I download links (to PDFs) with one click in Chrome for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, pdf, google-chrome

Usually when I option-click a single page link, Chrome tries to download the page, but when I option-click on PDFs, Chrome doesn't respond. Is this the default behavior and is there some way to change this? Also do other browsers allow for this type of one-click download? (I know if I turn off in-browser PDF reading that all PDFs would be downloaded, but I don't want that as the default action.)

Comment: Let me get that. I just tried in Chrome the Option > Click on a PDF file and it comes up with save as pop up offering to save it as ??

Comment: @Buscar웃: I tried that on several sites, including JSTOR, and it does nothing. Is it because I have Chrome PDF Viewer as well? Why would that disable the option-click?

Comment: This problem no longer exists as of today's current beta.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Chrome settings > Advanced

Click on privacy settings > Content

Scroll down to Plug ins

Click on

> Disable Individual plug-ins

Disable the

> Chrome PDF Viewer

That will unfortunately disable it for all PDF preview.

But the good news is

now you have the simple one click on a PDF link and it will offer you to download the PDF file.